# Grab the individual files to be deleted based on that information

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

**My problem right now is**: When the customer uploads an image. then the old image must be deleted when uploading.

That is, the first one goes in and deletes the old file and then after uploading the new file that one has uploaded.

I have made a service that just has to handle this information around errors etc.

If I copy the url then I get the right content out of it.

Therefore, I expect that I can only delete the file I am referring to in the image. **(Url)**

[image: Images here]

```
public async Task RemoveFile(string courseId, string imgName)
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(AzureHelper.ConnectionString);
        var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(courseId);
        await containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(imgName).DeleteIfExistsAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to split `imgName` to get the real image name:

```
    var arr = imgName.Split("/");
    var name = arr[arr.Length-1];
    await containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(name).DeleteIfExistsAsync();
```